# Distinct group to avoid duplicate depts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1

```
Dept    Class
A        x1
A        x2
B        Y1
B        Y2
```

and table2

```
Dept    
A   
B
```

I want to join both tables and count group by Dept if they are the same Dept (regardless Class)so I will have

```
CountDept  Dept
   1        A
   1        B
```

The goal to avoid duplicate dept on table 1 (even have more than class in the same dept on table1).

I tried distinct but not work

```
select distinct count(t1.dept)countdept, t1.dept, t1.class
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.dept = t1.dept
group by t1.Dept, t1.class
```

Comment: You mean a `COUNT(DISTINCT {expr})`?

Comment: Count what?  Your desired code is equivalent to `select 1, dept from table2`.

Comment: Count by dept . please see my query.

Comment: It's `COUNT(DISTINCT {expression})` not `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT({expression})`. If you are using `SELECT DISTINCT` in an aggregate query, then this strongly implies your `GROUP BY` or aggregates are wrong, as a `GROUP BY` would be already putting your data into distinct grouping sets.

Comment: So what the quey should like.Can you rewrite my query

Comment: There's no need, this is a typographical error, @user13636604 . I've shown you twice already how to count distinct values works in my comments.

Comment: Otherwise, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-count-and-distinct) shows you too.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation link. I got the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

by using partition by it is possible to do

```
;WITH tmp AS(
    select distinct  t1.dept, t1.class,
    row_number() over (PARTITION BY t1.dept
    order by t1.class ) as cnt
    from table2 t2
    join table1 t1 on t2.dept = t1.dept  
    )
    select * from tmp where cnt=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you want a join at all.

As Gordon said in the request comments, it seems you merely want to show table2.dept, each with a "count" of 1, which would simply be:

```
select 1 as count_dept, dept from table2;
```

If you only want to show those that also exist in table1, then use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
select 1 as count_dept, dept from table2 where dept in (select dept from table1);
```

Or, if you want to "count" zeros, too, then use `CASE WHEN`:

```
select 
  case when dept in (select dept from table1) then 1 else 0 end as count_dept,
  dept 
from table2;
```